# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host, didnt change anything

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

I am working on an old Flask sqlalchemy website which is run with docker-compose, started giving me this error.
I have tried changing the hostname in the app config, and going back to an old version from gitlab, but im not sure what else i can do.

here are all the relevant pieces of code i think that might be useful for you:

```
INIT.PY
from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mail import Mail
import os


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "FLASK_SECRET_KEY"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://flask:flask@db:5432/flask_dev"

app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 587
app.config["MAIL_USE_TLS"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = os.environ.get("MAIL_USERNAME")
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = os.environ.get("MAIL_PASSWORD")

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
mail = Mail(app)

from website import routes
```

```
APP.PY
from website import db, app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

```
DOCKER-COMPOSE.YAML
version: "3.3"

services:

  db:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=flask
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=flask
      - POSTGRES_DB=flask_dev
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:  
      - "5400:5432"
    networks:
      - backend
    restart: 
      always
    
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - backend
    restart: 
      always



volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  backend:
```

```
DOCKERFILE
FROM python

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install --requirement requirements.txt

COPY . /app/

CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

**FULL ERROR TRACEBACK**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-admin:~/Desktop/home-website-master/hawala-system$ docker-compose up 
[+] Running 3/3
 ⠿ Network hawala-system_backend  Created                                                                                                                     1.1s
 ⠿ Container hawala-system-db-1   Created                                                                                                                     3.7s
 ⠿ Container hawala-system-web-1  Created                                                                                                                     3.4s
Attaching to hawala-system-db-1, hawala-system-web-1
hawala-system-db-1   | 
hawala-system-db-1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
hawala-system-db-1   | 
hawala-system-db-1   | 2022-08-19 11:44:36.587 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
hawala-system-db-1   | 2022-08-19 11:44:36.587 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
hawala-system-db-1   | 2022-08-19 11:44:36.588 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
hawala-system-db-1   | 2022-08-19 11:44:38.419 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
hawala-system-db-1   | 2022-08-19 11:44:39.121 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-08-19 11:44:20 UTC
hawala-system-db-1   | 2022-08-19 11:44:40.493 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
hawala-system-web-1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
hawala-system-web-1  |   warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
hawala-system-db-1   | 2022-08-19 11:44:41.765 UTC [33] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.24.0.3", user "flask", database "flask_dev", no encryption
hawala-system-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
hawala-system-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
**EXTRA TRACEBACK REMOVED**
hawala-system-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
hawala-system-web-1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
hawala-system-web-1  | psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.24.0.3", user "flask", database "flask_dev", no encryption
hawala-system-web-1  | 
hawala-system-web-1  | 
hawala-system-web-1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
hawala-system-web-1  | 
hawala-system-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
hawala-system-web-1  |   File "/app/app.py", line 5, in <module>
hawala-system-web-1  |     db.create_all()
*unuseful
hawala-system-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
hawala-system-web-1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
hawala-system-web-1  | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.24.0.3", user "flask", database "flask_dev", no encryption
hawala-system-web-1  | 
hawala-system-web-1  | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Comment: "172.24.0.3" is not in your pg_hba.conf.  So what is in it?

Comment: " I have tried changing the hostname in the app config"  What does that mean?  Which line of what you quoted did you change?  What did you change it from?  What did you change it to?

Comment: @jjanes I dont know what a pg_hba.conf is, ive never touched it

Comment: @jjanes `app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://flask:flask@db:5432/flask_dev"` to `app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://flask:flask@localhost:5432/flask_dev"`

Comment: this worked perfectly fine yesterday, i have no idea what screwed it up.

Comment: "I dont know what a pg_hba.conf is"  If the person who handled this before is no longer available, then it seems like you best learn.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an old volume running, I removed all of them, then I added a healthcheck to my db service, and I made the web service depend on the db service to confirm that the service was healthy before attaching it self;
heres the updated code.

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - backend
    restart: 
      always

  db:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=flask
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=flask
      - POSTGRES_DB=flask_dev
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:  
      - "5400:5432"
    networks:
      - backend
    healthcheck:
        test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d $${POSTGRES_DB} -U $${POSTGRES_USER}" ]
    restart: 
      always

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  backend:
```